# Thumbnail in the blog

Tags: joomla-3.x

Does Joomla 3 has some default options to set a smaller image size in the Blog view (thumbnail) and the normal size in the article?

Answer (score 6):

Nope, not directly. Each article can have two different images:

The **intro image** is used for article teasers like a blog view or search results.

The **fulltext image** is used for the article view.

So you could use the same image but different sizes. Besides that you have always the possibility to create a template overwrite and alternate the output.

Comment: The exact size is dictated by the template used, correct? So switching templates could change the size if the template has code to affect it?

Comment: The original images can but should not be altered by template, but a template could create thumbnail/cached-image which will be displayed.

Comment: So I guess I could change some php (say components\com_content\views\category\tmpl\blog.php for this situation) so that it shows the image size I want.

Comment: And additional wish is to insert an image in the beginning of an article but hide it in the blog view. Maybe it's also can be achieved through the blog.php editing.

Comment: You should not edit the core files. Use overrides: `templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_content/category/blog.php`. See [Joomla Docs](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)